# Silverlight performance/profiling with AutomationPeers

Tags: performance, silverlight, profiling, ui-automation

For accessibility Silverlight implements AutomationPeers, useful for Automated UI tests, screen readers etc.

When profiling my SL app, I notice a lot of expensive calls related to AutomationPeers, such as [UIElement.OnCreateAutomationPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.oncreateautomationpeer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Framework controls have implemented this, which results in unmanaged code calls, which are obviously expensive from SL's managed code.

My question is, is this automation only enabled when you have an automation client running, like "Tablet PC Input Service"? I don't want these calls to be made because we will not be using any automation/accessiblity services, and our app is fairly resource intensive, so need to limit unnecessary calls, especially unmanaged ones.

I am just unsure if this code is executing due to some automation client I don't know about running on my system, or if this will be executed on the client's systems as well? I don't want to have skewed profiling results.

Comment: Thanks, actually your question contains answer to my problem. I was debugging some strange performance problems which appeared only on some machines - it turned out that when touch-enabled monitor was ever attached to the computer (Windows 7/8), this enables the mentioned service - Tablet PC Input Service - which in turn requires full automation tree on application's startup. As we were performing some heavy operations in some automation peers, this led to performance issue.